# How do I convert an ROS image into a numpy array?

Tags: sensor-msgs, rospy, ros-fuerte, compressedimage, morse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm trying to read ROS images published from a video camera (from MORSE) into a numpy array in my python script, but I don't know what is the correct way to do this, and everything I have tried hasn't worked.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is a snippet of what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy 
import rospy 
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

def vis_callback( data ):
  im = numpy.array( data.data, dtype=numpy.uint8 )
  doSomething( im )
rospy.init_node('bla',anonymous=True)
sub_vis = rospy.Subscriber('navbot/camera/image',Image,vis_callback)

rospy.spin()
```

I get an error that looks like this:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1370383204.000265] bad callback: <function vis_callback at 0x32e2398>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.15-py2.7.egg/rospy/topics.py", line 678, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "ros_simulate.py", line 55, in vis_callback
    im = numpy.array(data.data,dtype=numpy.uint8)
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: "':\x0f\xff';\x10\xff+A\x12\xff7Q\x16\xffB`\x18\xffGg\x18\xffDa\x15\xff=W\x12\xff2H\r\xff*<\x0b\xff&8\n\xff$6\t\xff%6\t\xff'9\n\xff*>\n\xff0G\x0b\xff8S\x0b\xff;Y\n\xff:X\t\xff8V\x07\xff6T\x06\xff2N\x04\xff-F\x04\xff+B\x03\xff&<\x03\xff(?\x05\xff#8\x07\xff\x1e0\x07\xff\x19)\x07\xff\x19(\x08\xff\x1b+\t\xff\x1e0\x0b\xff\x1e0\x0b\xff 3\x0c\xff\x1e1\x0b\xff\x1e1\x0b\xff\x1d/\n\xff\x1c-\t\xff\x1c,\t\xff\x1a*\x08\xff\x1d.\x08\xff(>\x0b\xff-F\x0c\xff<[\x0f\xffJo\x12\xffJp\x12\xffKr\x12\xffLs\x12\xffMt\x13\xffMu\x13\xff"
```

I noticed that the Image object has a deserialize_numpy() method, I couldn't find any documentation on how to use it, so I crossed my fingers and tried it out:

```
def vis_callback( data ):
  im = numpy.array(data.deserialize_numpy(data.data, numpy ), dtype=numpy.uint8)
  doSomething( im )
```

and got more errors:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1370383699.289428] bad callback: <function vis_callback at 0x34b5410>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros_comm-1.8.15-py2.7.egg/rospy/topics.py", line 678, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "ros_simulate.py", line 53, in vis_callback
    im = numpy.array(data.deserialize_numpy(data.data, numpy ), dtype=numpy.uint8)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sensor_msgs/msg/_Image.py", line 282, in deserialize_numpy
    raise genpy.DeserializationError(e) #most likely buffer underfill
DeserializationError: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64318/how-do-i-convert-an-ros-image-into-a-numpy-array?/) by [Albatross](https://answers.ros.org/users/4920/albatross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to deserialize the message data with [cv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge) first ([python tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython)). Once you have the image as a `cv.Mat`, you can just call `numpy.asarray` on it.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albatross](https://answers.ros.org/users/4920/albatross/) on 2013-06-05**:
Thanks! That worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've thrown together a package that tries to solve the "How can I convert ROS's <X> into a numpy array" class of problems: [ros_numpy](https://github.com/eric-wieser/ros_numpy). Using this, the solution becomes:

```
arr = ros_numpy.numpify(img_msg)
```

---

Originally posted by [eric-wieser](https://answers.ros.org/users/26065/eric-wieser/) with karma: 111 on 2016-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-27**:
That sounds quite useful! Can you provide a link to source code or documentation for your package?

**Comment by [eric-wieser](https://answers.ros.org/users/26065/eric-wieser/) on 2016-02-27**:
@ahendrix: The package name above is a link to the github repo, containing both of those things

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-27**:
excellent!

**Comment by [eric-wieser](https://answers.ros.org/users/26065/eric-wieser/) on 2016-04-11**:
This package is now published!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will do what you want, assuming you have an RGB image.  If not, you can check the `data.encoding` and add some extra logic.

```
import numpy as np
import rospy 
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg

def vis_callback( data ):
  im = np.frombuffer(data.data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(data.height, data.width, -1)
  doSomething(im)

rospy.init_node('bla', anonymous=True)
sub_vis = rospy.Subscriber('navbot/camera/image', numpy_msg(Image), vis_callback)

rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [matwilso](https://answers.ros.org/users/27246/matwilso/) with karma: 91 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5